# Retrieve and store boolean values in uitableview ios

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a list with a few rows, each row containing a switch. I would like to store the boolean values of the list (every time one is clicked) to nsuserdefaults , however im unsure of how to obtain each value. The switch is a [UICustomSwitch](http://www.catamount.com/blog/1063/uicustomswitch-customizing-uiswitch-color-it-change-labels/). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store booleans with

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setBool:NO forKey:@"myKey"];
```

Retrieve booleans with

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs boolForKey:@"myKey"];
```

To integrate this with a swtich, you can do the following;

Store booleans with

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setBool:mySwitch.on forKey:@"myKey"];
```

Retrieve booleans with

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[mySwitch setOn:[prefs boolForKey:@"myKey"] animated:YES];
```

Comment: thanks! how can I attach a listener to each row switch to know when to store the values?

Comment: don't forget to use `[prefs synchronize];` after setting the values!

Comment: Right, but how can I listen to the touch events on each uicustomswitch?

Comment: @mikez: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631442/synchronizing-plist-across-a-tab-bar-application/6631618#6631618) for how to set up notifications.